# Python WX buttons deployment issue

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I've encountered a peculiar problem while trying to deploy wx buttons on my GUI. Attached the following code section for explanation:

Initial declaration:

```
self.ButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.ButtonsBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
```

Loop that creates the buttons in the GUI:

```
        for i in range(0, len(self.ButtonsNamesList)):
            self.tButton = wx.ToggleButton(self.TestsPanel, -1, self.ButtonsNamesList[i], size=wx.Size(200, 60))
            self.tButton.SetMinSize((0, 34))
            self.tButton.SetValue(True)
            self.tButton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda evt, id=i: self.OnRelayButton(evt, id))
            # tButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.OnTestButton)
            self.ButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) #nullifies buttonsizer count. must find how to work without it.
            self.ButtonSizer.Add(self.tButton, 1)
            # tButton.SetMinSize((0, -1))
            self.ButtonsBox.Add(self.ButtonSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)

        self.TestsPanel.SetSizer(self.ButtonsBox)
```

When using "self.ButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)" inside the loop, the buttons are deployed correctly and the panel is being displayed as planned.

When removing this line from the loop, it creates a misplaced buttons array.

The problem is when using this line, it resets an important count property that I want to use later on.

I'm trying to find a way around it without destroying the displayed panel.

[Wrong buttons deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f0ig.png)

Thanks in advance,
Igal

Comment: When using `self.ButtonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)` inside the loop, you overwrite the initial declaration, and in every iteration you add to `ButtonsBox` a new sizer containing a single button, and at the end, the initially declared `ButtonSizer` will be the last sizer created in the loop, containing the last button. When you do not use the line above in the loop, thus you don't overwrite the initial declaration, you are _adding_ the same `ButtonSizer` multiple times to `ButtonsBox` (which is completely wrong).

Comment: Whatever counter that relies on `ButtonSizer` almost certainly would be provided by `ButtonsBox`. It too is a sizer and you add in each button, in a round about way. Or increment a specific counter. As a side note, creating new widgets in a loop as `instance variables` (self) is pointless as you are constantly over writing them. Outside of the loop, you will only be able to access the last occurrence.

Comment: @IgalNudelman, you probably meant to have an array of buttons and an array of sizers...

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, thank you for the answer. If I put ```self.ButtonsBox.Add(self.ButtonSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)``` outside of the loop, it creates all the buttons in 1 line in the upper part of the panel. How do I place them in a column, 1 under the other?

Comment: @IgalNudelman With code fragments it's often difficult to guess intentions. Use a `wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)` for vertical alignment. There's a `sizer` or combination of sizers for every layout.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony The weird thing is it doesn't matter if I set the BoxSizer to vertical or horizontal ```self.ButtonsBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)```, it still builds the inside buttons in a single row. I'm guessing that it might be something to do with the wx.EXPAND feature. Basically for this specific panel, it's not code fragments but the entire code.

Comment: @IgalNudelman We cannot see the entire code because you have only provided a code fragment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example